# Is the sum of a unimodal and increasing function still unimodal?

Tags: functions

There is no specific function. I would like to know if there is information on summation of a unimodal and increasing function? (Continuous functions)

Answer (score 1):

Not in general. $1-|x|$ si unimodal on $[-1,1]$, $1+x$ is increasing and the sum is not unimodal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want
everything analytic,
$1-x^2$
is unimodal
and 
$e^{.001 x}$
is increasing,
but their sum
has a peak near zero
and eventually
goes unboundsd.